# Using current.id in cypher query

Tags: structr

I cannot figure out how to use a current.id parameter in a Cypher query.

```
${cypher('MATCH ... WHERE p.id=\'${current.id}\' RETURN ...)}
```

I tried to concatenate the string using the ${concat()} function, but I only figured out that the Cypher query is not executed if there is another function in the string.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Cheers
Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `${}` you enter a StructrScript context and thus it would be `current.id` as opposed to another nested `${current.id}`. When trying to concatenate strings in StructrScript you can use the `concat()` function. I tested the following snippet locally to reproduce your problem:

```js
${
  cypher(
    concat('MATCH (p) WHERE p.id = \'',current.id,'\' RETURN p')
  ) 
}
```

Alternatively you could work in a JavaScript context invoked by `${{}}`. Within that context you can use Structr's in-built functions as well. E.g.:

```js
${{
var query = 'MATCH (p) WHERE p.id = \'' + Structr.current.id + '\' RETURN p';
var result = Structr.cypher(query);
Structr.print(result);
}}
```